# uiwebview and CSS text shadow

Tags: html, css, ios, uiwebview

I am having an annoying bug with uiwebview and CSS/HTML content:

[image]

As you can notice, some lines of text appears without the shadow effect. All the text is located inside the same div with same style. Why isn't uniform?

```
    #style
{
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color: #504f4f;
    text-shadow: #fff 0px 1px 0px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

I load the html page into a uiwebview as a modal view.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never seen `text-shadow` with the color first. I doubt that is your problem, but the syntax I'm familiar with looks like this `text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;`

Comment: What's the mark-up for the text element(s)?

Comment: I tried text-shadow in that way too but it's not the problem...

Comment: <div id="style">
      <li>gfhgfhfhgfgh<br>rrrrrr blalblalblalblalb s<br>ehs dfjkhsd fk<br>jsdhf sdfh sdfhas dfkjhs<br>ad fkajsdhf akdsjh adjha sdjkfha sdk<br>jfha dsjfhad jahsd fkajsdhf aisfh sdf<br>lh dflhas dfjlasd falsjdhf adlfjh asdhhhja sdfkjahsd flahjsdf asdljfh asdjfha sdfjlhasd f
      </li>
          </div>

Comment: I've noticed that if I increase the shadow text-shadow: #fff 0px 5px 0px; some lines have a thicker shadow than the others... In the same <div>. I don't understand anything :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its most likely to do with the zoom level of the UIWebView. There are many little display errors like this in UIWebView. It could well be solved my making your text strong, or increasing the text size.

Comment: Solution was deactivating 'Scales Pages to Fit' in IB.

Comment: up voting this and marking your question as answered would make mine.

Glad I could help. Tim